# Trouble Using SQL SELECT and then UPDATE in One PHP Function - MYSQL PHP ST EXECUTE PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, execute

UPDATE: Solved, thanks for the help everyone!

---

So I want to have a PHP function which queries the database for all encounters of type 'Check-out' and then updates the *persons* table field *lastCO* with the date of whichever of the encounters  is most recent.

But in my while loop for my UPDATE function seems to error out somehow. You can tell I put in an 'echo' statement just so I could see if the conditions of the loops were even being met, and indeed when I looked at the source it echo'd **one time**.

But when I comment out my second (UPDATE) SQL statement, the while loop seems to iterate properly (and my echo statement prints many, many times).

```
  public static function getLastCO() {

    $conn = new PDO( DB, DBU, DBP );

    $sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(encPastDate) AS encPastDate, encPastText,encPastPTRef
    FROM enctsPast WHERE encPastText = 'Check-out'";    
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();

    $row = $st->fetch();

       //trouble seems to start here!!!!

       while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {

         $person = new Person( $row );

         if ($person->encPastDate != null){
            echo '123abc456';
            $sql1 = "UPDATE persons SET lastCO = 
             (CASE WHEN lastCO < '$person->encPastDate' THEN '$person->encPastDate'                      
             WHEN lastCO = null THEN '$person->encPastDate' END)";  
            $st = $conn->prepare( $sql1 );
            $st->execute();
        }
    }
    $conn = null;
  }
```

So what is wrong with my UPDATE statement and execution? Is the problem the way I connect to two different tables while on the same 'connection'? Something else?

I am just having trouble debugging this, and my pitiful echo attempt isn't getting me far : /

### -

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php and it should be clear,,

but to create a new Persoon Object inside a while loop without using unset($persoon) after is bad memory management..
And creating a object inside a loop isn't very good better should be to reuse the same created object again and again and again something like below

```
$person = new Person();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {

     person->populateFromArray($row)
```

Comment: Thanks! I definitely knew my method was not the most efficient but was unsure how exactly find a better way. Will definitely read!

Comment: Still working on this. Are you saying my prepare statement is wrong soemhow? Reading the manual, but not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
WHEN lastCO = null
```

with:

```
WHEN lastCO is null
```

comparison between variable and NULL value must be done with IS NULL statement, otherwise is always UNKNOWN so your THEN branch has been not executed.

Another thing not right for me, in your query.

You use CASE but if lastCO is not null and is greater than of your variabile, the value of lastCO set to NULL so you may put ELSE branch to prevent this behaviour.

At the end, you can merge to query in only one UPDATE query without loop.

**Edit about answer of comment:**

Try this:
In this query you update all records of persons table because you haven't put a where clause

```
UPDATE persons
SET lastCO = 
CASE 
    WHEN lastCO < '$person->encPastDate'
    THEN '$person->encPastDate'                      
    WHEN lastCO is null
    THEN '$person->encPastDate' 
    ELSE lastCO = lastCO
END
```

In other way:
In this way you update only record of persons where lastCO is not valorized or if lower than variable '$person->encPastDate'

```
UPDATE persons
SET lastCO = 
CASE 
    WHEN lastCO < '$person->encPastDate'
    THEN '$person->encPastDate'                      
    WHEN lastCO is null
    THEN '$person->encPastDate' 
END
where lastCO is null or lastCO < '$person->encPastDate'
```

Third way:
You have a loop, every step you process a person. So you can limit your update at that person using in where clause:
persons.id = $person->id or other variable where has stored person ID.

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helped, though I am still having issues. "At the end, you can merge to query in only one UPDATE query without loop." -- Not quite sure what you mean there...

Comment: It is weird, even after that change the SQL query seems to be acting strange. The query does seem to be affecting all of my records, but all with the same value (I can see them getting changed by looking at the command line), but my echo statement only prints once. If I remove the SQL statement my echo statement repeats many times.

Answer (score -1):

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
```

Cant do something while an unbuffered query was running  in the WHILE loop.
Add the following line to ensure buffered queries are being used.

EDIT

Of course it does this you need a where condition in the sql.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am still having issues. I can see from the command line that my query is setting the lastCO field in my table for ALL of my persons, but my loop seems to break because it is pulling the same single date and inserting it into all records. And again when I comment out the SQL UPDATE line I get tons of echos in my source, but when I do it with SQL UPDATE still there i get one single echo in the source

Comment: Soemthing about the second SQL UPDATE statement is breaking my loop

Comment: Ah, you are right. Major lapse. However, it is still the same issue. When I run this function only one person record is being affected! I know the first SQL statement is working and getting a full list, but for some reason my UPDATE statement seems only doing it once. Something about the SQL statement itself is causing this (I think)